# Using Neo4j 3.1.5 with neo4j-elasticsearch 3.1.4

Tags: elasticsearch, neo4j, elasticsearch-plugin, neo4j-ogm

I am trying to link my Neo4j db with Elasticsearch using the recommended approach on the Neo4j website, with this GitHub repository https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-elasticsearch

I have done all the steps that they say to do, but when I run it in terminal I get this error (everything works normally except that nothing is getting pushed to Elasticsearch):

```
Failed to load `org.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger` from 
plugin jar 
`/Users/tkralj/Documents/Neo4j/default.graphdb/plugins/neo4j-
elasticsearch-3.1.4.jar`: org/apache/avalon/framework/logger/Logger
2017-07-13 20:21:46.911+0000 WARN  [o.n.k.i.p.Procedures] 

Failed to load `org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger` from 
plugin jar 
`/Users/tkralj/Documents/Neo4j/default.graphdb/plugins/neo4j-
elasticsearch-3.1.4.jar`: org/apache/log4j/Category
2017-07-13 20:21:46.911+0000 WARN  [o.n.k.i.p.Procedures] 

Failed to 
load `org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogKitLogger` from plugin jar 
`/Users/tkralj/Documents/Neo4j/default.graphdb/plugins/neo4j-
elasticsearch-3.1.4.jar`: org/apache/log/Logger
```

I am running Neo4j 3.1.5, while this plugin was created for 3.1.4 and I think that may be the issue; however, there is no plugin made for 3.1.5, and I cannot find a way to download the older version of Neo4j.

Comment: There is an alternative with Apoc procedures:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48518360/integration-of-elasticsearch-with-neo4j-database/48518760#48518760

Answer (score 1):

Looks like old question but still answering for future googlers.
I was facing the same problem with 3.1.x version . For me it's working fine with version 3.2