# Integrating Neo4j 3.3.3 with elastic-search

Tags: elasticsearch, neo4j, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-5

I was trying to integrate neo4j with elastic-search using https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-elasticsearch official docs.
I had placed neo4j-elasticsearch-3.2.3.jar file into /var/lib/neo4j/plugins directory  and changed neo4j.conf which was there given in the official docs.But now when i start neo4j.
 `sudo service neo4j start` and if i check`sudo service neo4j status`.It gives error.

[image]

I have cleared and installed neo4j couple of times but the problem still persists.Though there are many other similar looking questions as well closest being [Integration of elasticsearch with neo4j database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48518360/integration-of-elasticsearch-with-neo4j-database) but none of them seems to give a solution.

**Here is my /var/log/neo4j/neo4j.log file**

```
   Mar 02 10:32:59 nikhil-computer systemd[1]: Started Neo4j Graph Database.
Mar 02 10:32:59 nikhil-computer neo4j[12008]: Active database: graph.db
Mar 02 10:32:59 nikhil-computer neo4j[12008]: Directories in use:
Mar 02 10:32:59 nikhil-computer neo4j[12008]:   home:         /var/lib/neo4j
Mar 02 10:32:59 nikhil-computer neo4j[12008]:   config:       /etc/neo4j
Mar 02 10:32:59 nikhil-computer neo4j[12008]:   logs:         /var/log/neo4j
Mar 02 10:32:59 nikhil-computer neo4j[12008]:   plugins:      /var/lib/neo4j/plugins
Mar 02 10:32:59 nikhil-computer neo4j[12008]:   import:       /var/lib/neo4j/import
Mar 02 10:32:59 nikhil-computer neo4j[12008]:   data:         /var/lib/neo4j/data
Mar 02 10:32:59 nikhil-computer neo4j[12008]:   certificates: /var/lib/neo4j/certificates
Mar 02 10:32:59 nikhil-computer neo4j[12008]:   run:          /var/run/neo4j
Mar 02 10:32:59 nikhil-computer neo4j[12008]: Starting Neo4j.
Mar 02 10:33:00 nikhil-computer neo4j[12008]: 2018-03-02 05:03:00.100+0000 INFO  ======== Neo4j 3.3.3 ========
Mar 02 10:33:00 nikhil-computer neo4j[12008]: 2018-03-02 05:03:00.136+0000 INFO  Starting...
Mar 02 10:33:00 nikhil-computer neo4j[12008]: 2018-03-02 05:03:00.792+0000 ERROR Failed to start Neo4j: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@48bb62' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "org.neo4j.kernel.configuration.Settings.setting(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/function/Function;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/neo4j/graphdb/config/BaseSetting;". Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@48bb62' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "org.neo4j.kernel.configuration.Settings.setting(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/function/Function;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/neo4j/graphdb/config/BaseSetting;".
Mar 02 10:33:00 nikhil-computer neo4j[12008]: org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@48bb62' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "org.neo4j.kernel.configuration.Settings.setting(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/function/Function;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/neo4j/graphdb/config/BaseSetting;".
Mar 02 10:33:00 nikhil-computer neo4j[12008]:         at org.neo4j.server.exception.ServerStartupErrors.translateToServerStartupError(ServerStartupErrors.java:68)
Mar 02 10:33:00 nikhil-computer neo4j[12008]:         at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:219)
Mar 02 10:33:00 nikhil-computer neo4j[12008]:         at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:111)
Mar 02 10:33:00 nikhil-computer neo4j[12008]:         at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:79)
Mar 02 10:33:00 nikhil-computer neo4j[12008]:         at org.neo4j.server.CommunityEntryPoint.main(CommunityEntryPoint.java:32)
Mar 02 10:33:00 nikhil-computer neo4j[12008]: Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@48bb62' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "org.neo4j.kernel.configuration.Settings.setting(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/function/Function;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/neo4j/graphdb/config/BaseSetting;".
Mar 02 10:33:00 nikhil-computer neo4j[12008]:         at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:466)
Mar 02 10:33:00 nikhil-computer neo4j[12008]:         at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
Mar 02 10:33:00 nikhil-computer neo4j[12008]:         at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:211)
Mar 02 10:33:00 nikhil-computer neo4j[12008]:         ... 3 more
Mar 02 10:33:00 nikhil-computer neo4j[12008]: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory, /var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db
Mar 02 10:33:00 nikhil-computer neo4j[12008]:         at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:211)
Mar 02 10:33:00 nikhil-computer neo4j[12008]:         at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:126)
Mar 02 10:33:00 nikhil-computer neo4j[12008]:         at org.neo4j.server.CommunityNeoServer.lambda$static$0(CommunityNeoServer.java:58)
Mar 02 10:33:00 nikhil-computer neo4j[12008]:         at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase.start(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:88)
Mar 02 10:33:00 nikhil-computer neo4j[12008]:         at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:445)
Mar 02 10:33:00 nikhil-computer neo4j[12008]:         ... 5 more
Mar 02 10:33:00 nikhil-computer neo4j[12008]: Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.extension.KernelExtensions@5b218417' failed to initialize. Please see the attached cause exception "org.neo4j.kernel.configuration.Settings.setting(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/function/Function;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/neo4j/graphdb/config/BaseSetting;".
Mar 02 10:33:00 nikhil-computer neo4j[12008]:         at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:427)
Mar 02 10:33:00 nikhil-computer neo4j[12008]:         at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.init(LifeSupport.java:62)
Mar 02 10:33:00 nikhil-computer neo4j[12008]:         at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:98)
Mar 02 10:33:00 nikhil-computer neo4j[12008]:         at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:207)
Mar 02 10:33:00 nikhil-computer neo4j[12008]:         ... 9 more
Mar 02 10:33:00 nikhil-computer neo4j[12008]: Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.neo4j.kernel.configuration.Settings.setting(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/function/Function;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/neo4j/graphdb/config/BaseSetting;
Mar 02 10:33:00 nikhil-computer neo4j[12008]:         at org.neo4j.elasticsearch.ElasticSearchKernelExtensionFactory$ElasticSearchSettings.<clinit>(ElasticSearchKernelExtensionFactory.java:24)
Mar 02 10:33:00 nikhil-computer neo4j[12008]:         at org.neo4j.elasticsearch.ElasticSearchKernelExtensionFactory.newInstance(ElasticSearchKernelExtensionFactory.java:40)
Mar 02 10:33:00 nikhil-computer neo4j[12008]:         at org.neo4j.elasticsearch.ElasticSearchKernelExtensionFactory.newInstance(ElasticSearchKernelExtensionFactory.java:18)
Mar 02 10:33:00 nikhil-computer neo4j[12008]:         at org.neo4j.kernel.extension.KernelExtensions.newInstance(KernelExtensions.java:78)
Mar 02 10:33:00 nikhil-computer neo4j[12008]:         at org.neo4j.kernel.extension.KernelExtensions.init(KernelExtensions.java:61)
Mar 02 10:33:00 nikhil-computer neo4j[12008]:         at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:406)
Mar 02 10:33:00 nikhil-computer neo4j[12008]:         ... 12 more
Mar 02 10:33:00 nikhil-computer neo4j[12008]: 2018-03-02 05:03:00.794+0000 INFO  Neo4j Server shutdown initiated by request
Mar 02 10:33:00 nikhil-computer systemd[1]: neo4j.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 02 10:33:00 nikhil-computer systemd[1]: neo4j.service: Unit entered failed state.
Mar 02 10:33:00 nikhil-computer systemd[1]: neo4j.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 02 10:33:00 nikhil-computer systemd[1]: neo4j.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Mar 02 10:33:00 nikhil-computer systemd[1]: Stopped Neo4j Graph Database.
```

Kindly guide me a way to connect neo4j-3.3.3 with elastic-search or refer to some latest official docs.

Thanks in Advance 
Cheers

Comment: do you have some other errors inside `/var/log/neo4j/debug.log` ? Have you perform an upgrade of ubuntu ?

Comment: just a hint but if "all of a sudden" means after apt-get upgrade, then maybe it is worth looking for a version mismatch with the plugins you may have installed

Comment: Ok, it seems a bit awkward but the problem was that while integrating neo4j with elastic-search using this link github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-elasticsearch. I had placed neo4j-elasticsearch-3.2.3.jar file into /var/lib/neo4j/plugins directory which was there given in the official docs and then only neo4j stopped working.I have edited the question accordingly.